# When am I to use ContentProvider

Tags: android

I am a little bit confussed. I will like to know when am to make my database a contentprovider. Im developing a project that uses db, but I see no reason why I should convert my sqlite db to content provider. If there is any advantage for doing that pls let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

> You don't need to develop your own provider if you don't intend to
>   share your data with other applications. However, you do need your own
>   provider to provide custom search suggestions in your own application.
>   You also need your own provider if you want to copy and paste complex
>   data or files from your application to other applications.